# Vector functions applied to a football game

Tags: calculus, physics

A wide receiver is standing $40$ ft to the left ($x=-40ft$) of the quarterback who is standing at the origin. The receiver immediately accelerates at $\displaystyle 9.79 \frac{ft}{s^2}$ at an unknown angle and catches the football directly in front of the quarterback.  If the quarterback counts to $3$ (seconds) before launching the ball, what is the unknown angle? What are the receiver's coordinates at the moment he catches the ball? Air resistance is neglected.

Other info: The quarterback throws the ball at a constant velocity of $\displaystyle 80.67 \frac{ft}{s}$. Acceleration due to gravity is $\displaystyle -32 \frac{ft}{s^2}$

This is a question for a math class.  I have spent around $4$ hours trying to figure it out.

Comment: Follow-on question: the defending linebacker accelerates at 8.7 ft/sec^2, and hits the receiver at the time of reception. How many games does the receiver miss due to his concussion?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:  Let $\theta$ be the angle between the receiver's path and the $+x$ axis.  The receiver's position at time $t$ is $\frac 12\cdot 9.79 t^2(\cos \theta,\sin \theta)-(40,0)$  We have that the receiver's position at the catch has $x(t)=0$  We have to assume the altitude of launch are altitude of reception are the same, though this is not specified.  Let $\phi$ be the elevation angle of the release of the ball.  Measure $z$ from the elevation of the release and catch. The ball position is $(0, 80.67 \cos \phi t, 80.67 \sin \phi t - \frac 12 \cdot 32 t^2)$  This gives three equations in three unknowns.  Not an easy one.